# Sort the Items with Stored Procedure

Tags: sorting, stored-procedures

So I have following example from my database:

```
"John"   "1"
"Diva"   "1"
"Christ" "2"
"Azzam"  "2"
"Sunny"  "3"
"Daniel" "3"
"Alex"   "4"
"Mike"   "4"
```

Two Names can have same NameID. Now I want to sort in such a way that when I pass the parameter "NameID" it will show Name related to that Id at first and the other Name close to that ID respectively. Example If I pass the parameter "3" to Stored Procedure the result should be:

```
"Sunny"  "3"
"Daniel" "3"
"Alex"   "4"
"Mike"   "4"
"Christ" "2"
"Azzam"  "2"
"John"   "1"
"Diva"   "1"
```

What I did till now?

```
Select * From Database
Order by NameID
```

I couldn't go further than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a CTE or subquery to assign a weight to the matching NameIDs.  Then use that weight so those names appear first in the result set.

Here's an example from SQL Server, but the basic idea can be used in almost any SQL dialect:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @name_id_parameter INT = 3;

DECLARE @names TABLE
  (
    [name] NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
    [name_id] INT NOT NULL
  );

INSERT INTO @names
  (
    [name],
    [name_id]
  )
  VALUES
  ('John', 1),
  ('Diva', 1),
  ('Christ', 2),
  ('Azzam', 2),
  ('Sunny', 3),
  ('Daniel', 3),
  ('Alex', 4),
  ('Mike', 4);

/* Solution #1: Using a common table expression (CTE) */

WITH cte([name], [name_id], [sort_weight])
AS
(
  /* Assign a higher "weight" to the [name_id]s that match
     @name_id_parameter, so those [name_id]s will appear
     first in the final result set. */
  SELECT
      [name],
      [name_id],
      CASE
        WHEN [name_id] = @name_id_parameter THEN 1
        ELSE 0
      END
    FROM
      @names
)
SELECT
    [name],
    [name_id]
  FROM
    cte
  ORDER BY
    [sort_weight] DESC, [name_id] DESC

/* Solution #2: Using a subquery */

SELECT
    S.[name],
    S.[name_id]
  FROM
    /* Assign a higher "weight" to the [name_id]s that match
       @name_id_parameter, so those [name_id]s will appear
       first in the final result set. */
    (SELECT
        [name],
        [name_id],
        [sort_weight] =
          CASE
            WHEN [name_id] = @name_id_parameter THEN 1
            ELSE 0
          END
      FROM
        @names) AS S
  ORDER BY
    S.[sort_weight] DESC, S.[name_id] DESC
```

Comment: @user49867, did you see my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Here is I think what you want:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( name VARCHAR(20), id INT )
INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 'John', '1' ),
        ( 'Diva', '1' ),
        ( 'Christ', '2' ),
        ( 'Azzam', '2' ),
        ( 'Sunny', '3' ),
        ( 'Daniel', '3' ),
        ( 'Alex', '4' ),
        ( 'Mike', '4' )

declare @id int = 3

SELECT * FROM @t
ORDER BY ABS(@id - id), @id - id, name
```

Output:

```
name    id
Daniel  3
Sunny   3
Alex    4
Mike    4
Azzam   2
Christ  2
Diva    1
John    1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @ID AS NVARCHAR(50)
SET @ID = '3';

SELECT  *
FROM    ( SELECT TOP(100)
                    [Name] ,
                    [NameID]
          FROM      [Test].[dbo].[Table_1]
          WHERE     NameID = @ID
          ORDER BY  NameID DESC
        ) a

UNION ALL

SELECT  *
FROM    ( SELECT TOP(100) 
                    [Name] ,
                    [NameID]
          FROM      [Test].[dbo].[Table_1]
          WHERE     NameID  @ID
          ORDER BY  NameID DESC
        ) b
```